# Real Analysis Carothers Chapter 1 Exercise 47

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}x & x∈\mathbb Q\\ 0 & x∈\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \\ \end{cases}, \qquad k(x) = \begin{cases}1/n & x=m/n∈\mathbb Q\\ 0 & x∈\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q \\ \end{cases}.$$

Prove that $g(x)$ is continuous at $0$ and nowhere else in $[0,1]$. Prove that $k(x)$ is continuous only at $x = a$, where $a$ is an irrational number in $[0,1]$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: These functions are called [Dirichlet function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_function) and [Thomae's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). Now that you know the name, it should not be difficult to search on this site (or elsewhere) for proofs showing where they are continuous.

Answer (score 1):

To see that $g$ is continuous at $0$, note that $-|x| \leq g(x) \leq |x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ by definition of $g$. By the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = 0 = g(0)$, so $g$ is continuous at $0$.

Suppose $x_0 \neq 0$; we show that $g$ is not continuous at $x_0$. To that end, we find some $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ and every pair of distinct points $u, u' \in U$, we have $|g(u') - g(u)| \geq \epsilon$. Since every neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ contains both irrational and rational numbers, there is some rational $u \in U\cap \mathbb Q$ such that $g(u) = 0$, and there is some irrational $u'_\varepsilon \in U \cap (\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q)$ such that $g(u'_\varepsilon)$ is arbitrarily close to $x_0$: 
$$
\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists u'_\varepsilon > 0 : \qquad |x_0 - g(u'_\varepsilon)| < \varepsilon.\tag{1}
$$ 
But then $|g(u'_\varepsilon) - g(u)| = |g(u'_\varepsilon)|$ cannot be made arbitrarily small by adjusting $U$ (since it's arbitrarily close to $|x_0| \neq 0$, and $x_0$ is always in $U$), and hence $g$ is not continuous at $x_0$. More formally, starting with $(1)$ and using the reverse-triangle inequality, 
$$
\varepsilon > |x_0 - g(u'_\varepsilon)| \geq \big| |x_0| - |g(u'_\varepsilon)| \big| \implies |g(u'_\varepsilon)| > |x_0| - \varepsilon.
$$ 
Selecting $\varepsilon$ (and thus our choice of $u'_\varepsilon$) so small that $|x_0| - \varepsilon > 0$ shows that $g$ doesn't satisfy the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity with $\epsilon = |x_0| - \varepsilon$, since for all $\delta$, $|u - u'|<\delta$ (by adjusting $U$), but $|g(u'_\varepsilon) - g(u)| = |g(u'_\varepsilon)| \geq |x_0| - \varepsilon = \epsilon$.

Now for $k$. If $x_0 \neq 0$ and $x_0 = m/n \in \mathbb Q$, $k$ is discontinuous at $x_0$ for the same reason that $g$ is; just replace $x_0$ with $1/n$ in our above argument, and it will go through. $k$ is not well-defined at $0$, but it's true that $\lim_{x \to 0} k(x) = 0$.

Now, we show that if $a \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$, then $k$ is continuous at $a$. The moral of the story here is that since $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, there exists a sequence of rationals approximating $a$,
$$ 
q_j = m_j/n_j \to a,
$$
and since $a$ is irrational, we need infinitely large denominators to do so, hence $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} k(x) = \lim_{j \to \infty} k(q_j) = \lim_{j\to\infty} 1/n_j = 0 = k(a)$, and $k$ is continuous at $a$.

Comment: Thanks for the first one. I edited the second. Now what do you think about the k function?